# Web Api Service HTTP status code 405 on method POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

GET works fine.
But in Chrome with POST method I have:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed).
Failed to load http://localhost:49834/api/Rest/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.
In InterntExplorer I have: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network error 0x80070005, Access denied.

Controller:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public class RestController : ApiController
    {
// POST: api/Rest
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Request Request)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Requests.Add(Request);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <!-- add this -->
    </modules>  
    <handlers>      
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

AJAX POST:

```
var url = "http://localhost:49834/";
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url + "api/Rest/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(submitData),
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
                }
            })
```

I use IIS Express: applicationHost.config file in %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config folder => ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 handler is configured like this verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"

GET works fine:

```
$.getJSON(url + "api/Rest").done(function (data) { 
                    var mass = new Array();                 
                    $(data).each(function (index, e) {
                        ReqArray.push(e);
                    })
                    vm.requests(ReqArray); 
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with my ajax, like this it works good:

```
var url = "http://localhost:49834/";
    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url + "api/Rest",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: submitData,
                        success: function (data) {
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: It's good that you pointed out the error yourself but it's equally important to know why this worked - The 'API' created by you expects the 'HTTP' verb as 'POST' while calling it otherwise it returns 405(Method Not allowed). By default 'getJSON' method sends request with 'GET'  'HTTP' verb and passing the verb explicitly through 'ajax' method solved your problem. 

Cheers!!!